# Complex query filter using Like() in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing a SQL script that we want our accounting team to be able to edit, without dealing with engineering.

The general idea is to have a .sql script, which defines some variables at the top of the query, and then has several complex queries below it that use those variables.

The problem we have is that we want the accounting team to be able to specify the filter to use.  For example:

```
DECLARE @year INT
DECLARE @month INT
DECLARE @filter VARCHAR(30);

SET @year = 2010
SET @month = 7
SET @filter = '%test%'
```

Here the team can change the month and the year that the subsequent queries return.  They can also define ONE filter element, in this example, excluding any records where the username has the string `'test'` in it.

My question is whether or not there is a way to specify OR's to a `LIKE()`.  Eg, ideally we'd have the `@filter` variable as something like `'%test%`, or `%other%`.  Now I know that's not real syntax, but I'm wondering if there is syntax that lets me achieve that.  I've scowered MSDN on the `LIKE()` syntax with no joy.  Should I use some different query expression?

Comment: You could use CLR and Regular Expressions for this. There is no `|` operator in the Like pattern syntax. Or you could pass in the various literals in a TVP (assuming SQL Server 2008) and Join onto that with `LIKE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing to do would be to just have multiple parameters, though it's not pretty:

```
SET @filter_1 = '%test%'
SET @filter_2 = '%foo%'
SET @filter_3 = '%'
SET @filter_4 = '%'

SELECT *
FROM BAR
WHERE var LIKE @filter_1
   OR var LIKE @filter_2
   OR var LIKE @filter_3
   OR var LIKE @filter_4
   OR var LIKE @filter_5
```

By defaulting them to %, they will always match by default.

You could also use dynamic SQL and a local table variable.  Basically, create a local table with one column, allow them to change the INSERT statements into that table, then define a loop that iterates over the contents of that table to dynamically generate the LIKE clauses.  It would work, but it would be a bit more code.  The example above is quick and dirty, but I'd guess it's probably sufficient for what you need to do.

Comment: thanks I'm going with this.  Like you say, its not pretty - but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a join with a `LIKE` predicate. You can execute the following code sample in a query window to see how this works:

```
DECLARE @tblFilter TABLE
    (sFilter nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL);
INSERT @tblFilter 
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('%one%'), ('%two%'), ('%three%')) v(s);

DECLARE @tblData TABLE 
    (iId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
     sData nvarchar(MAX));
INSERT @tblData(sData) 
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('one'), ('two three'), ('four')) v(s);

SELECT DISTINCT iId 
    FROM @tblData d 
    JOIN @tblFilter f ON d.sData LIKE f.sFilter;
```

I assume that the different query strings are in the `@tblFilter` table, which could be a TVP, coming from XML values, from comma-separated values, from a temp table or whatever.